# Less less.modifyVars not working in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, less

I am trying to change the variable of LESS on the fly via HTML in an AngularJS function. I wrote the same code and ran on xamp, with simple HTML, CSS it works. Now when I put the same code in the enterprise app in Visual Studio, it doesn't work. The variables compile, the function works. Just that the less.modifyVars doesn't work, and it doesn't change on the fly. This is how my HTML looks

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="~/Content/brandnew.less">
<script>
var less = {
    logLevel: 0,
    env: "development"
};
</script>
<script src="~/Content/less.min.js"></script>
```

In the body

```
 <form ng-submit="changeLess()">
                Enter text and hit enter to change color:
                <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

My less file.

```
@color: #f16e8d;
.custom-anchor-color {
    color: @color;
}
```

And my JS function. This is the exact same function, I ran on my localhost. But it doesn't work on the VS.

```
$scope.changeLess = function() {
            if ($scope.text) {
                debugger;
                less.modifyVars({
                    color: $scope.text
                });
                console.log($scope.text + ' inside $scope.text')
            }
        }
```

It is logging the function properly, but the variable color doesn't change. I tried keeping it as 'color' as well with the quotations.

Comment: which version of less.js is being used in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug. The app was already rendering the code beforehand, and hence there weren't any variables left in the LESS file because it was rendered. This is possible in VS by using dotless. This is how the code looks for it.

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

More about can be found here. http://www.dotlesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
less.modifyVars({
  '@color': $scope.text
});
```